# Auditing a `svn merge`?

Tags: svn, svn-merge

Something odd just happened.  Only half the changes to a file in `trunk` were applied to `tags/version` during a `svn merge -r 1234:HEAD`.  I can't figure out how / why.  The only way I was able to update the tags/version was to physically copy the file.

That being said, is there a good way to "audit" trunk vs tags/version.  the only thing I can think of is to `svn export` both directories, and then diff the two.  I'm wondering if there is a more elegant / simple solution.